# HR person is non responsive

Tags: human-resources, canada

No need to a great deal of details, but basically my HR person has been lax in her responsibilities in regards to issueing/following-up on my maternity/EI requirements with the government.

To put it in perspective, I have been back to work for more than 3 months and before this off for over a year of maternity leave.

This should have been more than enough time to fix her problems, which I have had to hound and repeatedly ask her to do so.

I do not feel I should have to follow-up so much or that this process should have gone to this extreme length/time frame.

She has made many mistakes! It has now come to my attention that these mistakes will end-up affecting my credit rating as she has failed to do the proper paperwork, which I have asked her to correct which resulted in an over payment from EI.

What is the best course of action to get this rectified quickly?

I would like to e-mail her, point-out the entire timeline, each request and how long it took to get resolved and which pieces that are still outstanding and cc her boss. I don't believe she has been doing her job to the level that is acceptable and would like her boss to be aware. Is this course of action appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: `She has made many mistakes! It has now come to my attention that these mistakes will end-up affecting my credit rating as she has failed to do the proper paperwork, which I have asked her to correct which resulted in an over payment from EI.` Who is EI?

Comment: EI = Employment Insurance, at least within Canada that is what we call it.

Comment: I have seen the following in two separate instances: Someone is hired to handle phone calls and mail and pay the bills, and after some point the business owners and employees started having problems like what you're describing. At some point the owner or manager would be checking through this person's desk looking for something and would find all the mail in the bottom drawer unopened - in short, the 'administrative assistant' had done absolutely nothing for months. If you can get this person's boss to check, this is likely to be what you'll find.

Comment: Sadly, she is not an admin but the manager of personal/communications and has been with the company for many years. I am not the first to go on maternity leave - so I am just frustrated at how much of a debacle this has become. I don't think this is a legal issue, am just looking for help with my course of action. Thanks

Comment: @user12420 - it sure sounds like you need to get someone else involved, either run this up through your chain of command or speak to the highest level manager on-site. Texas has something called the 'Texas Workforce Commission' that intervenes in wage disputes - people claiming that they're due pay for work when the employer isn't coming through.  I suspect Canadian provinces have something similar.  It would make sense to approach this agency if you can't get anyone to act within your organization - generally these deal with all kinds of employment issues.

Answer (score 7):

> What is the best course of action to get this rectified IMMEDIATELY!

- First of all, none of us can wave a magic wand and help you rectify this immediately; but the fact that your credit rating and standing with the government have been compromised by this HR person's incompetence mean that you may need to take some uncommon measures to rectify this situation quickly.
- Second, your best course of action is to **thoroughly document everything that has happened.** Detail each time that you communicated with the HR person so that you can articulate and establish the fact that she hasn't taken the appropriate actions.
- Third, after you've documented everything that has happened, print it, sign it, and send the HR person **and her boss** a copy by way of [certified mail](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_Mail) so that you can retain proof that the relevant parties have received your communication. In that email, indicate that everything needs to be resolved by two weeks from the date of your mail, and that if it is not, then <strike>will</strike> may take **legal action**.
- Fourth, if after two weeks, things are not resolved to your satisfaction, then it is up to you as to how you should proceed. You could simply drop by her desk again, call her on the phone, raise the issue with her boss again, or in fact take legal action against the firm. It might go without saying - Legal action is expensive, so you should only take this step if you've exhausted all of your other options.

Comment: I'm not sure that threatening legal action before even trying to escalate the issue to her boss is a great idea.

Comment: @Carson63000 You raise a fair point. Perhaps the OP's next move *should* be: Alert the HR person's boss. [Please see my edit.] However, I can't shake the fact that the OP's credit rating and standing with the government has been adversely impacted by this HR person's incompetence. To put it bluntly, this issue is as serious as a heart attack. It needs to be rectified ASAP.

Comment: Cheers Jim, I think this is an excellent answer with that extra step.